# Saving Edittext and making it stay on EditText

Tags: java, android

I have an app where I take the Name of the user in an editText and I have it storing to firebase but when I get out of the activity and go back into it, the editText field does not show the Name of the user anymore. I want their name to stay in the editText field.
also how would I do the same thing but for an image in an ImageView that the user puts in. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**IDEA:** 
You can use shared preference. When user launches his application first task will be load his user name and password from shared preference.

By doing this you can also manage a session manager for better user experience.

**For example:** After every successful authentication you can store the basic information of the user that is needed to update the screen everytime.

**Benefit:**
This will help you to show old data on screen if user launches your app without internet enabled. You can check the internet and if disabled then simply show the old data from preference.

Answer (score 0):

You Can do something like this

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                            int count)
{
  prefs.edit().putString("autoSave", s.toString()).commit();
}

@Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                int after)
{
}

@Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
{
   //At here you can call some method to get the text from shared preferences and display it on EDitText

}
```

or You can save into DB at onTextChanged() method

Comment: this is the half answer, it would be nice to show the op how to load the string from SharedPreferences at activity's restart

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little activity example which saves the username into SharedPreferences at stop of activity and restores the value to the EditText when activity is (re)started:

```
public class Test extends Activity {

    EditText edtUser;
    SharedPreferences preferences;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        edtUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUser);
        edtUser.setText(preferences.getString("username", ""));



    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        preferences.edit().putString("username", edtUser.getText().toString()).commit();

    }



}
```

Comment: Thanks this is the answer!

Comment: how would I do the same thing but for an ImageView @Chris623

Answer (score 0):

Set on click listener to edit text.
Inside on click enable edit text and write to firebase using setValue.

Set on click to parent layout or check is focus changed of edit text. Inside read from firebase using add value event listener.

In Oncreate disable edit text and read from firebase using add value event listener.

This will auto save and retrieve edit text data seamlessly.

In OnCreate create method of activity

```
//Initialize edittext

mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);

// Disable mEditText

mEditText.setEnabled(false);

//Read from firebase and set text to mEditText if mTextEdit is not in focus

if (!mEditText.isFocused()){
    mFirebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String editTextData = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            mEditText.setText(editTextData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}
    });
}

// Set onclick listener to mEditText

mEditText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mEditText.setEnabled(true);
        editTextData = mEditText.getText().toString();
        mFirebaseRef.setValue(editTextData);
    }
});
```

This works for me and UI looks simple without any extra buttons to switch between edit and save.

Hope I understood your requirement correctly. Thanks